# Build a regex pattern from dynamic folder path string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to iterate folders with `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` and check if there are folders starting with a specific pattern in each path.

```
static void SearchFolder(string searchDirectory)
{
    foreach (var path in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(searchDirectory))
    {
        var pattern = folderName + @"\10.*";
        var isProjectFolderMatch = Regex.Match(path, pattern);

        if (isProjectFolderMatch.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"found: {path}");

        }
    }
}
```

But the regex match throws an error

> 'C:\Folder\10.*' - Reference to undefined group number 1.'

How can I build a dynamic pattern in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `@"10.*"` pattern? Note, that `\1` means "1st capturing group" in regular expressions

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to attach the pattern to the end of the folderName variable

Comment: is that necessary to add the `foldername` into the pattern? since it is in the same `foldername` loop

Comment: folderName might not be the best name, EnumerateDirectories return the full path, not just the folder name, so it looks more like "C:\Folder\SubFolder" not just "SubFolder"

Comment: To match a backslash with regex, it must be doubled. `@"\\1"` or `"\\\\1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that you are looking for [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class: having, say, `c:\MyData\MyPath\10folder` you want to match `10` within `10folder`. If it's your case:

```
static void SearchFolder(string searchDirectory) {
  var folders = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(searchDirectory)
    .Where(path => new DirectoryInfo(path).Name.StartsWith("10"));

  foreach (var folderName in folders)
    Console.WriteLine($"found: {folderName}");
}
```

In case you want *regular expression*, put it as

```
     .Where(path => Regex.IsMatch(new DirectoryInfo(path).Name, "10.*"));
```

Please, note that `"10.*"` pattern means starting from `10`, when you original pattern `@"\10.*"` uses `\1` which means *1st capturing group*.

Comment: It looked like the string had escaping backslash \\. Your suggestion didn't quite answer the direct question about how to build a dynamic path pattern, but it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @mottosson: please, note, that valid path can have *different* separators: `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`, e.g.  `c:/MyData/MyPath/10folder` is a valid path.That's why hardcoding *back slash* can be a bad idea, when `DirectoryInfo` works with whatever separators